# While reading a file in java how to detect we have a line?

Tags: java

I am reading a file Java, using this code :

```
File file = new File(--path-);

Scanner reader= new Scanner(file);

while(reader.hasNext()){

    // i want to add here if reader.Next() == emptyline
    // I tried if reader.Next()=="" but it did not work.

}
```

thank you all

Comment: Have you tried `if(reader.hasNextLine())`? Please read [API Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine())

Answer (score 0):

next() reads words and skips blanks.

I suggest you use

```
while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    if(line.isEmpty()) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try looking at [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

```
String line = reader.nextLine ();
while (line != null) {

  if (line.length () == 0) {
     System.out.println ("zero length line");
  }
  else {
    System.out.println (line);
  }
  line = reader.nextLine ();
}
```

or

```
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {

  line = reader.nextLine ();
  if (line.length () == 0) {
     System.out.println ("zero length line");
  }
  else {
    System.out.println (line);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to read all the lines, you can simply use:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
```